# Forbidding touch event for underneath View inside FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my activity I use `FrameLayout` as a root container. Inside I've placed `SlidingDrawer` and osmdroid `MapView`. When my `SlidingDrawer` *is opened and I touch it*, `MapView` *also receives touch event and tiles are moved.* How do I fix this? Here's my layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tilesource="MapquestOSM" />

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextViev />
        <RelativeLayout>
            <Button/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</FrameLayout>
```

I use the `FrameLayout` because it enables desired layout positioning. Maybe there is another way to do what I want?

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Are you consuming the touch event? i.e., You return `true` from `onTouchEvent(...)` to indicate it has been handled? Post your code - the XML layout doesn't really help.

Comment: I don't handle touch event manually. MapView handles it on its own. So does the Drawer. Or I need to override Drawer's TouchEvent so it doesn't get passed to the MapView?

Comment: "Or I need to override Drawer's TouchEvent so it doesn't get passed to the MapView?" - It might be worth a try. It suggests the default `SlidingDrawer` implementation of `onTouchEvent(...)` isn't consuming it and it's passing it on to other views. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Simply returning true doesn't work. I need to implement SlidingDrawer touch event myself then. Still looking for something easier :)

Answer (score 4):

you can set the top layout like android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the onClick event of your view that appears in front of the mapview, I just did that and works! :D